# Can I run Hbase and Hadoop in my linux system without root permissions?

Tags: hdfs, hbase

I have been looking to study hbase and hdfs working .Can I Install them in my Linux system for which I dont have root permissions

Answer (score 0):

Of course you  can  give you some setting  I think it could help you
**Extract and install HBase

Configure HBase

Start and verify HBase**

Hadoop clusters need to be built.

1, (1) decompression installation

```
[zkpk@master ~] $CD /home/zkpk/resources/software/hadoop/apache

[zkpk@master apache] $mv~/resources/software/hadoop/apache/hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz~/

[zkpk@master apache]$CD

[zkpk@master ~] $tar -zxvf ~/hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz

[zkpk@master ~] $CD hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2
```

(2) configure HBASE

Enter the HBase installation home directory, and then modify the configuration file:

```
[zkpk@master ~] $CD /home/zkpk/hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2/conf
```

Modify environment variable hbase-env.sh

Open the file with the following command:

```
[zkpk@master conf]$GEDIT hbase-env.sh
```

The front part of the document has the following line:

```
Export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/
```

Amend the contents of the conversion to:

```
Export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/
```

Modify configuration file hbase-site.xml

Replace the original hbase-site.xml with the following contents:

```
<? XML version= "1"? >

<? Xml-stylesheet type= "text/xsl" href= "configuration.xsl"? >

<configuration>

<property>

<name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>

<value>true</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.rootdir</name>

<value>hdfs://master:9000/hbase</value>

</property>

<property>

<name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>

<value>master</value>

</property>

</configuration>
```

Set regionservers

Modify the localhost in regionservers to the following:

Slave

Setting environment variables

Edit the system configuration file and execute the following code:

```
[zkpk@master ~] $GEDIT ~/.bash_profile

Add the following code to the end of the file:

Export HBASE_HOME=/home/zkpk/hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2

Export PATH=$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH

Export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HBASE_HOME/lib/*

Then execute source ~/.bash_profile.
```

Copy HBase installation files to HadoopSlave nodes

Use the following commands to operate:

```
[zkpk@master ~] $SCP -r ~/hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2 slave:~/
```

(3) start and verify HBase

Enter the HBase installation main directory and start HBase:

```
[zkpk@master ~] $CD /home/zkpk/hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2

[zkpk@master hbase-0.98.9-hadoop2]$bin/start-hbase.sh
```